# Parse JSON inside JSON attribute using JSONPath

Tags: jsonpath

I have a JSON list where one of the attributes of each element happens to be a JSON itself. It comes from a poor design upfront, but here it is.

I want to query the distinct attributes inside the JSON string contained in the elements.

Here is an example, just one item. I hand-wrote the code, but believe me that is valid JSON in production by the way it's generated

```json
[{
  "extraData": "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
}]
```

I would like to query for something like `$.*.extraData.foo`, but obviously such syntax does not work.
I am using IntelliJ IDEA Jsonpath evaluator.

The syntax should be something like `parse($.*.extraData).*.foo`

[This article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E60058_01/PDF/8.0.8.x/8.0.8.0.0/PMF_HTML/JsonPath_Expressions.htm) suggests me that no such operator is available to parse a JSON inside a JSON

It **has** to be JSONPath only for data analysis purposes. In Java, I use Jackson to parse the `extraData` object as a `JsonNode`, but my goal is to explore the large data set, and perhaps obtain some distinct values I want to use for enumeration purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To JSON Path, the embedded JSON is just a string.  The best you could do with a single operation is use a RegEx in the expression selector, but getting RegEx to identify JSON is really tricky, and that's if your implementation even supports RegEx.

I think the best option would be to use two paths:

1. The first path gets the embedded JSON. `$.*.extraData`
2. Parse that value
3. The second part gets the data you need. `$.foo`

This requires some extra code, but I think it's your only realistic option.